# Trigonometric limits.

Tags: trigonometry

While solving a question I encountered an inequality saying that

$$\frac{\tan(3\phi)}{\tan(\phi)} \lt \frac13, 3 \lt \frac{\tan(3\phi)}{\tan(\phi)}$$.
I tried to solve the inequality. I used the calculus derivative method and was able to get the right hand side but as its a trigonometric question I want a trigonometric method to do it. Though its also clear for small angles, but how do I apply it in general.

I also tried to do it by using the identity of $tan(3\phi)$ and used the identity making the function

$$ \frac{tan(3\phi)}{tan(\phi)}= \frac{3tan(\phi)-tan^3((\phi))}{tan(\phi)(1-3tan^2(\phi)}$$ I cancelled the tangents  and got

$$ \frac{tan(3\phi)}{tan(\phi)}= \frac{3-tan^2((\phi))}{(1-3tan^2(\phi)}$$

What else need to be done to get both the sides of inequality.

Give answers based only on trigonometric method.

Comment: actually is $\frac{\tan(3\phi)}{\tan(\phi)} \in \mathbb{R} - [\frac13, 3]$

Comment: @Emisor I am sorry if I am wrong but my book mentioned it in this way only. Can you please help me with the proof.

Comment: i just plotted it and verified that it can't be like you posted originally. For example, $\frac{\tan(\pi)}{\tan(\pi/3)} = 0$

Comment: @Emisor, its right the book had a printing error but still i am not able to prove it. I have already edited that error. Thank You.

Comment: I don't know if there are trigonometric methods to find extremes in a relation. Anyway, in this case, the extremes coincide with the points in which the tangent goes to zero and infinity.

Comment: Any way you can use $\displaystyle y = \frac{3\tan \theta-\tan^3 \theta}{\tan \theta \cdot (1-3\tan^2 \theta)} = \frac{3-\tan^2 \theta}{1-3\tan^2 \theta}.,$ Now Put $\tan \theta = x\in \mathbb{R}.$ So we get $\displaystyle y = \frac{3-x^2}{1-3x^2}\Rightarrow y-3yx^2=3-x^2\Rightarrow (3y-1)x^2 = y-3\Rightarrow \displaystyle x^2=\frac{y-3}{3y-1},$ Now Using $x^2\geq 0\forall x \in \mathbb{R}$